# Why does the subdomain redirect requests back to parent domain?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, http, nginx, amazon-route53

I have a subdomain **sub.example.com** that is pointing to a web server hosted on an EC2 instance.

- In the AWS Route53 console I've created an A-record that points to the public EIP of that instance.
- I've checked the DNS records with `nslookup` and they look ok.
- I can access the subdomain web server from the browser using its public IP address.

But if I try to access using the domain name, the browser redirects the request to the parent domain: `http://sub.example.com` -> `http://example.com`. I'm using Nginx as a reverse proxy & NodeJs as a backend server.

What do I need to do to make it work?

**Edit**
I'm able to access it if I use the www. prefix ([www.sub.example.com](http://www.sub.example.com)). But without the "www" the browser just redirects me to the parent domain..

**nginx.conf**

```
user nginx;

worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                        '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                        '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 4096;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name sub.example.com www.sub.example.com;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        # Redirect all HTTP request to the node.js
        location / {
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_pass "http://127.0.0.1:5000";
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your expected output? You would only like to route sub.x.com and not x.com? Or both to be routed to the ECC2 instance?

Comment: @Ermiya Eskandary I expect that subdomain to be accessible with "www.sub.x.com" or "sub.x.com". But it does redirect me to the parent domain if I don't use the "www" part.

Comment: It sounds like you only have a DNS record for `www.sub.example.com` pointing at the EC2 instance. You also need to add a DNS A record for `sub.exammple.com` that points to the EC2 instance.

Comment: @MarkB I have A-record for "sub.x.com" > ip and ALIAS-records for "www.sub.x.com" > "sub.x.com".

Comment: Can you provide your nginx configuration as well?

Comment: I just dont understand why it redirects me to the parent domain if I omit the "www" part...

Comment: Is it a layer 7 redirect (301/302)? You can run ``curl -i http://sub.example.com`` and look for e.g. ``HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently``.

Comment: @maslick curl shows the 301 redirect for htt://sub.ex.com > http://ex.com. But I've never specified that redirect in any config or application code.. Where it comes from?

Comment: @IlyaLevi it's nginx (or better say your custom nginx.conf)

Comment: @maslick 'curl --trace-ascii - sub.example.com' shows incorrect IP. Maybe the dns resolver has cached old dns records and I have to wait until it updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the dns resolver cache. It has cached obsolete A-records that point to old IPs. After the dns cache has been updated the problem was gone.

Thank you @maslick for your replies.

Comment: please, accept my answer as a reward for the effort ;) thnx

Comment: I have made some minor edits to your question. Please, check if they are ok.

Comment: An up-vote on the answer is also welcome  thnx

Answer (score 1):

- Create two type "A" DNS records in Route53 (`xxx.yyy.zzz.aaa` is the public IP address of your EC2 instance, e.g. `18.185.121.30`):

```
sub.example.com -> xxx.yyy.zzz.aaa
www.sub.example.com -> xxx.yyy.zzz.aaa
```

- Use the standard `nginx` configuration (do not specify any DNS name in `server_name` - use the default value instead i.e. `server_name  _;`):

```
user nginx;

worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                        '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                        '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 4096;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name _;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        # Redirect all HTTP request to the node.js
        location / {
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_pass "http://127.0.0.1:5000";
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
    }
}
```

- Both the client (browser) and server (nginx) might be caching responses from an old configuration. Use your browser's Incognito mode or `curl` with a `no-cache` header to test:

```sh
curl -I -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" http://sub.example.com
```

- Be patient. DNS records require some time (time to live or TTL) to propagate across the globe. You can reduce TTL in Route53 and wait less.
- To debug DNS issues, use this Linux command:

```sh
dig -t a sub.example.com
```

I also like [this](https://dnschecker.org/) web-service which can help you track DNS propagation globally.

---

UPDATE: here's the example `node.js` web server I'm running on port 5000:

```js
var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  if (req.url == '/') {
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
    res.write('<html><body><p>This is home Page.</p></body></html>');
    res.end();
  }
});

server.listen(5000);
console.log('Node.js web server at port 5000 is running..')
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I already have those Route53 A-records. I have stopped the nginx service. And even with nginx service stopped, curl shows the 301 redirect to http://example.com.. I just don't know what to think at this point.. may be some AWS bug..

Comment: Change ``/etc/nginx/ngninx.conf`` with the configuration above. Restart the nginx service ``sudo systemctl restart nginx.service`` and try again. I have tried the above solution on a clean system. And both DNS names resolve to the same page without any redirects. You can also try to decrease TTL on your DNS records. Keep in mind, that your DNS changes need some time to propagate depending from where (geographically) you are making requests. Cleaning your browser cache might also help.

Comment: Nginx might be caching your requests. So try this command to tell nginx not to cache: ``curl -I -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" http://sub.example.com``

Comment: 'curl --trace-ascii - sub.example.com' shows incorrect IP. Maybe the dns resolver has cached old dns records.

Comment: yes, wait and/or reduce TTL

Comment: From you nginx configuration I can see you are redirecting / to another webserver (node.js) running on port 5000. Your node.js server might as well introduce redirects, change response headers, etc. Try with a simple test by serving a static page first (default nginx landing page will suffice, see my example config). Then gradually increase complexity - this way you will be able to pin-point the issue.

Comment: I have tried to reproduce your use-case with a simple node.js server running on port 5000. See the updated nginx.conf (there's only one line different from yours ``server_name _;``). I have tried to run it and it worked as expected. No 301 redirects whatsoever. Requests to both ``http://www.sub.example.com`` and ``http://sub.example.com`` return the same 200 response. See the updated answer. HTH ;)