# Redirecting a subdomain to an S3 bucket while main site is hosted on Wordpress?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dns, subdomain, amazon-route53

We've got a main website ([www.example.com](http://www.example.com)) which is hosted on Wordpress. I've built a replacement site which I've hosted in AWS S3 (test.example.com.s3-website-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/). The DNS records for the main website are hosted on Route 53.

I'd like the replacement site to be accessible from test.example.com while keeping the main site running. (Updated) I've got the following DNS records in Route 53:

```
example.com A   Simple  -   
xx.xx.xx.146

example.com MX  Simple  -   
0 example-com.mail.protection.outlook.com

example.com NS  Simple  -   
ns-2031.awsdns-61.co.uk.
ns-251.awsdns-31.com.
ns-638.awsdns-15.net.
ns-1284.awsdns-32.org.

example.com SOA Simple  -   
ns-2031.awsdns-61.co.uk. awsdns-hostmaster.amazon.com. x xxxx xxx xxxxxxx xxxx

example.com TXT Simple  -   
"v=spf1 include:spf.protection.outlook.com -all"
"MS=msxxxxxx"
"google-site-verification=xxxx"

_sipfederationtls._tcp.example.com  SRV Simple  -   
xxx x xxxx sipfed.online.lync.com

_sip._tls.example.com   SRV Simple  -   
xxx x xxx sipdir.online.lync.com

api.example.com A   Simple  -   
xx.xx.xx.146

autodiscover.example.com    CNAME   Simple  -   
autodiscover.outlook.com.

lyncdiscover.example.com    CNAME   Simple  -   
webdir.online.lync.com

msoid.example.com   CNAME   Simple  -   
clientconfig.microsoftonline-p.net

sip.example.com CNAME   Simple  -   
sipdir.online.lync.com

test.example.com    CNAME   Simple  -   
test.example.com.s3-website-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com.

www.example.com A   Simple  -   
xx.xx.xx.146
```

However, browsing to test.example.com still brings me to the main site, not the replacement site.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are saying that `test.example.com` resolves to an IP address associated with `www.example.com`? That sounds unlikely, given your CNAME configuration. If you resolve `test.example.com` to an IP address, is it the same IP address as your WordPress server?

Comment: Yeah, that's correct: when I browse to test.example.com it resolves to the same IP address as www.example.com. I've added the rest of the route table above in case anyone can help figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use an `A` **alias** record in Route53 instead of `CNAME`.

Also, make sure you:

- Name your bucket **exactly** as your DNS name, e.g. if your DNS name is `test.example.com`, then your bucket name should read `test.example.com`
- Enable `Static website hosting` on your bucket
- Regarding security, set the `Block public access` setting to `Off` and
- Apply the following Bucket policy:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Statement1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::test.example.com",
                "arn:aws:s3:::test.example.com/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

---

If done according to the instructions above, there won't be any complications. However, if you misconfigured sth before, you would need to be patient since DNS records require some time (time to live or TTL) to re-propagate across the globe. You can reduce TTL in Route53 and wait less. Additionally, your browser and the OS are caching DNS records, so it's better to flush DNS settings, e.g. on a Mac you could use:

```sh
$ sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder
```

To debug DNS issues, use `dig` or `nslookup` (they output should point to the IP address of S3):

```sh
$ dig -t a test.example.com
$ nslookup test.example.com
```

I also like [this](https://dnschecker.org/) web-service which can help you track DNS propagation globally.

---

I would recommend to put your static S3 website behind CloudFront. You will benefit from its low latency and high transfer rates for your end users. Also, your S3 bills will be noticeably reduced (if served to a large number of users).

And last but not least, you will be able to serve your static web-site via `https`. Your current solution works via `http` only.

Comment: I tried replacing the previous addition with the following, but still resolving to www.example.com: test.example.com A Simple - 
s3-website-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com.

Comment: are you sure it's an *alias* record (A type)? Maybe try on a different PC/smart phone? Clean browser cache, flush DNS on your PC?

Comment: also see my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70047062/why-does-the-subdomain-redirect-requests-back-to-parent-domain/70047904#70047904

Comment: On a Mac I would flush DNS with ``sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder``

Comment: See the updated answer

Comment: Tried the dig and nslookup recommendations. Output: test.example.com resolves the CNAME to example.com. Same for anything else I put as a subdomain: sample, foo, foobar, etc. I read something about wildcard DNS records, but I can't see where I've accidentally done that. Help?

Comment: Do you have an external (to AWS Route53) DNS registrar? Or did you register example.com with AWS Route53?

Comment: It would be better if you attached a screenshot from your Route53 hosted zone (exampe.com), blur out sensitive info